# Gforth's double precision utime

Tags: time, forth, gforth

From the [Gforth manual](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Keeping-track-of-Time.html#Keeping-track-of-Time):

> #### 5.29 Keeping track of Time
>
> [...]
>
> `utime       – dtime        gforth       “utime”`
>
> Report the current time in microseconds since some epoch.

Testing this, Gforth gives:

```
utime  ok
.s <2> 1486782751117149 0  ok
```

=> I don't understand the `utime` word. The first number on the stack obviously contains the timestamp in microsecond. But why, please, is the second just *zero?* Is this something peculiar to the 64-bit version? Is my code still interoperable if I just drop the second number and only work with the first?

Comment: Set your time to some time after 2038. Test again. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem See also: https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Double-precision.html#Double-precision

Comment: @ninjalj ok. Thanks a lot, as an answer I would have accepted it.